# xcode custom cell opacity not working on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i`m working on custom cells and everything works fine when i test on iOS 5 simulator, but when i checked on iOS 4 simulator there was a problem. the opacity of the cell background image is not working

this is on iOS 4

[image: http://i45.tinypic.com/fa0xl5.png]
[image]

and this is on iOS 5, witch i want it to look like in iOS 4

[image]

method i`m using is

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabelCellEb.png"]];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabelCell.png"]];}
```

and in the `viewDidLoad` for the table background is

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableBackground.png"]];
```

any idea how to solve this ?

UPDATE : this is the cell BG image i`m using

[image]

it has an effects on it and a %30 opacity

Update2:

New Images

[image]
[image]

now the background image is moving up and down with the table after replacing with that code

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TableBackground.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem,

i removed the `tableView willDisplayCell` method and added this code to the `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabelCellMu.png"];
UIImageView *cellBackgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cellImage];
cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundImage;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabelCell.png"]];
```

and everything worked fine in both iOS 4 and 5 :)